# description box jumps up

Tags: lyx, subfloats

[image]i am trying to add this two picture one above the other. the problem is that the description boxes keep jumping above the image when i go to pdf. any thoughts on how to force it to be below the image? the each image and its matching box is in a different sub-float.
thanks 
[image: the pdf after compiling the lyx]

```
\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset Caption Standard

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset


\begin_inset CommandInset label
LatexCommand label
name "paths"

\end_inset


\begin_inset Float figure
placement H
wide false
sideways false
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset Caption Standard

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset Graphics
    filename path_x_y .png
    lyxscale 26
    width 95col%

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset


\begin_inset Newline newline
\end_inset


\begin_inset Newline newline
\end_inset


\begin_inset Box Boxed
position "b"
hor_pos "c"
has_inner_box 1
inner_pos "t"
use_parbox 0
use_makebox 0
width "95col%"
special "none"
height "1in"
height_special "totalheight"
thickness "0.4pt"
separation "3pt"
shadowsize "4pt"
framecolor "black"
backgroundcolor "none"
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout
המסלול במישור 
\begin_inset Formula $x-y$
\end_inset

 של כדור פוליתאתילן ברדיוס 
\begin_inset Formula $3.684\pm0.921\mu m$
\end_inset

 בתמיסה של גליצרול-מים בריכוז של
\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\strikeout off
\xout off
\uuline off
\uwave off
\noun off
\color none

\family default
\series default
\shape default
\size default
\emph default
\numeric on
\bar default
\strikeout default
\xout default
\uuline default
\uwave default
\noun default
\color inherit
40
\numeric off
% בטמפ' החדר.
 ניתן לזהות את כי קיימת סחיפה של הכדור לאורך הקו המקווקו הירוק.
 נקודות ההתחלה והסיום של המסלול בפרק הזמן הנמדד מסומנות בהתאמה.
\begin_inset CommandInset label
LatexCommand label
name "path xy"

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset VSpace vfill
\end_inset


\begin_inset Float figure
placement H
wide false
sideways false
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset Caption Standard

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset Graphics
    filename normelized_path_x_y.png
    lyxscale 25
    width 95col%

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset


\begin_inset Newline newline
\end_inset


\begin_inset Box Boxed
position "b"
hor_pos "c"
has_inner_box 1
inner_pos "t"
use_parbox 0
use_makebox 0
width "95col%"
special "none"
height "1in"
height_special "totalheight"
thickness "0.4pt"
separation "3pt"
shadowsize "4pt"
framecolor "black"
backgroundcolor "none"
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout
ניתן לראות את המסלול המנורמל של כדור פוליתאתילן ברדיוס 
\begin_inset Formula $3.684\pm0.921\mu m$
\end_inset

 בתמיסה של גליצרול-מים בריכוז של
\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\strikeout off
\xout off
\uuline off
\uwave off
\noun off
\color none

\family default
\series default
\shape default
\size default
\emph default
\numeric on
\bar default
\strikeout default
\xout default
\uuline default
\uwave default
\noun default
\color inherit
40
\numeric off
% בטמפ' החדר.
 לאחר ביצוע הטרנספורמציה לביטול הסחיפה.
 כלומר במערכת צירים בה אין סחיפה.
 ניתן לזהות כי הכדור מבצע בקירוב תנועה סביב מיקומו ההתחלתי.
\begin_inset CommandInset label
LatexCommand label
name "normelized path"

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows how you produced the included screenshot.Without seeing the code it is impossible to guess why the alignment is not how you expected.

Comment: thanks for your reply i edited the post

Comment: I added the `lyx` tag, since you seem to use it. I have also improved the formatting of the added code. To do so, you can highlight the code and press the `{}` button.

Comment: The example is not complete. It should be a complete document. Please read https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample